# How to create a Carousel using reactstrap and getting data from props?

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to ReactJS, and I'm trying to create a Carousel inside my project, using Reactstrap. I copied the code from the documentation, and made my customizations as below:

```
class Example extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = { 
            activeIndex: 0
        };

        this.next = this.next.bind(this);
        this.previous = this.previous.bind(this);
        this.goToIndex = this.goToIndex.bind(this);
        this.onExiting = this.onExiting.bind(this);
        this.onExited = this.onExited.bind(this);
    }

    onExiting() {
        this.animating = true;
    }

    onExited() {
        this.animating = false;
    }

    next() {
        if (this.animating) return
        const nextIndex = this.state.activeIndex === this.items.length - 1 ? 0 : this.state.activeIndex + 1;
        this.setState({ activeIndex: nextIndex });
    }

    previous() {
        if (this.animating) return
        const nextIndex = this.state.activeIndex === 0 ? this.items.length - 1 : this.state.activeIndex - 1;
        this.setState({ activeIndex: nextIndex });
    }

    goToIndex(newIndex) {
        if (this.animating) return;
        this.setState({ activeIndex: newIndex });
    }


    render() {
        const { activeIndex } = this.state;

        const items = this.props.items

        const slides = items.map((item) => {
            return (
                <CarouselItem
                    onExiting={this.onExiting}
                    onExited={this.onExited}
                    key={item.id}
                >

                    <img src={item.img} alt={item.title}/>
                    <CarouselCaption captionText={item.title} captionHeader={item.title} />
                </CarouselItem>
            );
        });


        return (
        <Carousel
            activeIndex={activeIndex}
            next={this.next}
            previous={this.previous}
        >
            <CarouselIndicators items={items} activeIndex={activeIndex} onClickHandler={this.goToIndex} />
            {slides}
            <CarouselControl direction="prev" directionText="Previous" onClickHandler={this.previous} />
            <CarouselControl direction="next" directionText="Next" onClickHandler={this.next} />
        </Carousel>
        );
    }
}


export default Example;
```

I'm passing to the component the list of items as props and getting it inside the render(). As my value comes from an async, the component renders twice: once with props null and again after receiving the props values, thus updating {const items} and {const slides} values.

**But inside the functions previous and next, the value of {this.items} is always undefined. How can I make these functions see the {items} after it got the values?**